# What does =+ mean and why does it compile?

Tags: c#, operators

I've got the following typo:

```
subcomponentGroupCount = +subcomponentCount;
```

used in the following:

```
int subcomponentGroupCount = 0;

foreach (Subcomponent subcomponent in group.Subcomponents)
{
    int subcomponentCount = task.TaskDevice.TaskDeviceSubcomponents.Count(tds => tds.TemplateID == subcomponent.TemplateID);
    subcomponentGroupCount = +subcomponentCount;
}
```

I intended it to be +=, but I'm left wondering what "= +var" means..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `+` operator can be used as a binary *or* a unary operator. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx):

> Unary + operators are predefined for all numeric types. The result of a unary + operation on a numeric type is just the value of the operand.

You can overload this operator for custom types, but for the built-in numeric types, this is essentially a no-op.